# play flv using netStream appendBytes

Tags: actionscript-3, flv, netstream, urlstream

I know that there are many ways to play an FLV file but considering my project requirements, I need to play the flv using URLStream and NetStream

here's the complete sample code that I'm doing my tests on:

```
package 
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.Event;
    import flash.events.NetStatusEvent;
    import flash.events.ProgressEvent;
    import flash.utils.ByteArray;
    import flash.net.URLRequest;
    import flash.net.URLLoader;
    import flash.net.URLLoaderDataFormat;
    import flash.net.NetStreamAppendBytesAction;
    import flash.net.NetConnection;
    import flash.net.NetStream;
    import flash.media.Video;
    import flash.net.URLStream;

    /**
     * ...
     * @author Hadi Tavakoli
     */
    public class Main extends Sprite 
    {
        private var netConnection:NetConnection;
        private var netStream:NetStream;
        private var ul:URLStream;
        private var video:Video;
        private var bytes:ByteArray = new ByteArray();
        private var _isSeek:Boolean = false;

        public function Main():void 
        {
            if (stage) init();
            else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event = null):void 
        {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            // entry point

            video = new Video();
            addChild(video);

            netConnection = new NetConnection();
            netConnection.addEventListener(NetStatusEvent.NET_STATUS, netConnectionStatusHandler);
            netConnection.connect(null);
        }

        private function netConnectionStatusHandler(ev:NetStatusEvent):void
        {
            switch(ev.info.code)
            {
                case 'NetConnection.Connect.Success':

                    ul = new URLStream();
                    ul.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, onProgress);
                    ul.load(new URLRequest('01.flv'));

                break;
            }
        }

        private function onProgress(e:ProgressEvent):void
        {
            ul.readBytes(bytes, bytes.length);

            if (!netStream) 
            {
                netStream = new NetStream(netConnection);
                netStream.client = { };
                video.attachNetStream(netStream);
                netStream.play(null);
                trace("BEGIN")
                netStream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_BEGIN);
            }
            else
            {
                if (!_isSeek)
                {
                    trace("SEEK")
                netStream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.RESET_SEEK);
                    _isSeek = true;
                }
            }

            if (bytes.length == e.bytesTotal)
            {
                trace("END")
            netStream.appendBytesAction(NetStreamAppendBytesAction.END_SEQUENCE);
            }

            netStream.appendBytes(bytes);
            trace("-")
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if I am using "appendBytes" method correctly? the video is shown but only a very few first frames will play and then the video stops!

in my eyes it seems all ok! do you have any advice on where my problem is?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need the if (!_isSeek) block.  It looks like you are pushing the bytes as you receive them in a sequential order and so there's never a seek.  It looks like it will push the first set of bytes and then append a seek action and append the rest of the bytes.  Try just removing that block and see if it works.

Otherwise I think it's ok.

Answer (score 0):

in "ul.readBytes(bytes, bytes.length);" line, there is a bug i guess. It's never worked for me also. It always return full length (from 0 to the available bytes). So It have a huge memory leak. But if you are using flash player 11.4 or later, you can change it like this.

```
ul.position = bytes.length;
ul.readBytes(bytes);
```

Comment: Regarding "..in `ul.readBytes(bytes, bytes.length);` line, there is a bug i guess. It's never worked for me also..". **There is no bug**. You are feeding incomplete frame bytes and that jams the decoder. Each progressEvent cycle does not automatically stop/start at some next frame's bytes so if you only got frames 8 and half worth of bytes at cycle 1 then cycle 2 brings in some halfway bytes (of 8) that are not full frame data it will jam. Either append per x-num of frames amount of bytes or wait for all bytes and then append when progressEvent complete

Comment: In that progressEvent function use appendbytes only in this line `if (bytes.length == e.bytesTotal) { trace("END"); netStream.appendBytes(bytes);  }` This will append when all bytes are available and therefore no freezing.